# How add a value at the end of each line to file which have 2 million lines in a CSV file?

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark, rdd

This is my data:

```
1   2693    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
1   2694    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
1   2695    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
1   2696    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
1   2697    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
.
.
.
1   2697    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0
```

I want to convert it to :

updated file should like bellow format

i want to add just a single string value to each line

```
1   2693    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
1   2694    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
1   2695    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
1   2696    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
1   2697    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
. 
.
.
1   2697    1   80  1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   40  0   0  Attack
```

i want to write a program in Scala to perform the above task.

the program should count to total line in data and then run the loop as many time.

the at each iteration the program should assign a specific string value to each line.

At the end the program should write the new updated data to a new file.

This a Python code that solved my problem but i want the code that do the same in Apache spark (Scala) .

```
 import csv
 output = open('processed.csv', 'w')
 with open("hping3Spoofed.csv") as csvFile:
 csvLines = csv.reader(csvFile)
 id=0
 documents = []
 for line in csvLines:
        if(id == 0):
               line.append("label \n")
               id = 1
        else:
               line.append("Spoof Attack \n")

        output.write(', '.join(line))
```

Comment: You never mentioned `apache-spark` but you have it in the tag: is this a spark related question or a simple "vanilla scala" answer would be fine?

Comment: also, is it always the word "Attack", or might it depend in some way on the data in that line?

Comment: and that's not CSV there, y'know... i assume your file is?

Comment: finally, is there a specific reason you want to use scala for this? i love scala, but for a one-off task, it sounds like `perl -i -pe 's/$/,Attack/' file.csv` would do the trick.

Comment: my file name is spootedAttack.csv

Comment: agree with @RobStarling there are multitudes of single line shell commands to handle this. one other example could be `sed -e 's/$/ Attack/' -i filename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Rob and @kali:

```
import sys.process._
"perl -i -pe 's/$/,Attack/' spootedAttack.csv" #> new java.io.File("out.csv") !
// or
"sed -e 's/$/ Attack/' -i spootedAttack.csv" #> new java.io.File("out.csv") !
```

If you want to add some logic based on the line content and you could access ~160MB of RAM:

```
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import scala.io.Source.fromFile
import scala.io.Source.fromInputStream

// from the "src/main/resources" dir
// val ob = fromInputStream(getClass.getResourceAsStream("/spootedAttack.csv"))

val ob = fromFile("spootedAttack.csv", "UTF-8")
           .getLines
           .map(_ + " Attack") // write your logic here
                               // e.g. .map(line => if(line...) ...)
           .mkString("\n")
           .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Files.write(Paths.get("output.csv"), ob)
```

Comment: If you don't need to use fancy logic to determine what to add at the end of the line, I would use @Rob or @kali suggestions using `sed` or `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

This a Python code that solved my problem

```
import csv
output = open('processed.csv', 'w')
with open("hping3Spoofed.csv") as csvFile:
   csvLines = csv.reader(csvFile)
   id=0
   documents = []
   for line in csvLines:
            if(id == 0):
                   line.append("label \n")
                   id = 1
            else:
                   line.append("Spoof Attack \n")

            output.write(', '.join(line))
```

Comment: That is an answer to a different question though :( It would help you to get answers if your question actually described what you need. There's no mention of the header line in your question.

Comment: 1. Have a trivial problem solvable with any shell   
2. Tag your question with `scala`, `apach-spark` and `rdd`
3. Post self-answer written in python
4. ...
5. HATS!!!

Comment: yeah sir but still i want the code that work the same as my python code working, i have some english problem , so i can't express well

Comment: This is an "update" to your question! Please delete it and add it to your question...